# React Native + Jest EMFILE: too many open files error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, ulimit

I am trying to run Jest tests, but I'm getting the following error:

> Error reading file: `/Users/mike/dev/react/TestTest/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/yeoman-environment/node_modules/globby/node_modules/glob/node_modules/path-is-absolute/package.json`
>   /Users/mike/dev/react/TestTest/node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/node-haste/lib/loader/ResourceLoader.js:88
>         throw err;
>         ^
>
> Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open '/Users/mike/dev/react/TestTest/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/yeoman-environment/node_modules/globby/node_modules/glob/node_modules/path-is-absolute/package.json'
>       at Error (native)
>   npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.

What is interesting to me is that the path listed in the error points to a file in the node_modules directory, which I expected would not be read because of the node_modules entry in testPathIgnorePatterns.

I'm running Node 4.2.1, my install of React-Native is only a week old, I installed Jest today (so I think I'm up to date with everything).  I'm on a Mac.

I have run: `sudo ulimit -n 10240`, closed all Terminal windows, and even tried a reboot.  (In my .bash_profile I had previously added `ulimit -n 1024`.  And I've tried even larger numbers.

To make sure the problem is not just in my own project, I created a new project with `react-native init TestTest` and made RN's suggested changes to the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "TestTest",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node_modules/react-native/packager/packager.sh",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react-native": "^0.14.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "scriptPreprocessor": "node_modules/react-native/jestSupport/scriptPreprocess.js",
    "setupEnvScriptFile": "node_modules/react-native/jestSupport/env.js",
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/",
      "packager/react-packager/src/Activity/"
    ],
    "testFileExtensions": [
      "js"
    ],
    "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
      "promise",
      "source-map"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest-cli": "^0.7.1"
  }
}
```

But I'm getting the same error every time.

Comment: After trying other options, I ended up having success with `brew install watchman` according to this forum post https://www.bountysource.com/issues/37982520-watch-mode-stopped-working-on-macos-sierra

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer: adding 'ulimit -n 4096' to ~.bash_profile and opening a new terminal window resolved my issue.

The answer had to do with me not setting the ulimit properly.

```
sudo ulimit -n 10240
```

on my Mac silently doesn't change the ulimit.  I had originally thought it was not doing anything because 10240 is not an increment of 1024.  But it also didn't do anything when I tried 2048, 4096, etc.

So, what is "the" solution?

- ulimit -n   (without a number) will tell you what the current value is
- for me, typing `sudo ulimit -n 2048` in a terminal window did NOT change the ulimit (no matter what number I tried)
- adding 'ulimit -n 4096' to ~.bash_profile and opening a new terminal solved the problem

Comment: If you remove the `sudo` and just call `ulimit -n 10240` it should work on OSX

Comment: resetting the ulimit didn't help me

Answer (score 26):

I had the same problem with a small vuejs project. In my case the fix was just a small configuration property: I put this in to my `jest.config.js`

```
  watchPathIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules'],
```

For anyone withe the same problem with vuejs. Here's my full `jest.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  preset: '@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest',
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/(?!(leaflet))'],
  watchPathIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules'],
  testMatch: [
    '<rootDir>/src/**/*.spec.js'
  ],
};
```

Comment: Awesome! Worked like a charm

Comment: This one worked for me, on my new MacBook Air with M1 CPU.

Comment: works for `NextJS` apps as well (MacOS, Intel)

Comment: This solution worked on mac - NodeJS 16 environment / ExpressJS framework

Comment: Works for Quasar framework too

Answer (score 4):

I'm running windows in powershell.  Also used Git Bash and had similar problems.  I updated my package.json as follows:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest-cli": "^0.8.2",
  },
  "jest": {
    "testPathDirs": ["__tests__"],
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
```

Note that `"testPathDirs": ["__tests__"],` is the directory I place all my tests in.

Now I can run `npm test` without an issue.  Ultimately it seems Jest is navigating the `/node_modules/` directory which should be excluded.

Comment: This solved my problem. For anyone using react-scripts (create react app), you'll have to replace "testPathIgnorePatterns" with "watchPathIgnorePatterns".

Comment: Thank you sir! this actually solves the problem rather dodge it. for CRA, just changing jest option `watchPathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_module/']` should fix it. Jest is running test inside of node_modules. installing watchman does not solve that it just make jest power through using resources and slowing down tests

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this problem and fixed it by running

```
brew upgrade watchman
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue some time ago but couldn't figure out why jest was not ignoring my node_modules folder.

What I ended up doing is changing `"testFileExtensions"` from `["js"]` to `["spec.js"]` and renaming all the tests with the extension `.spec.js`

Not the proper solution but gives me time until seeing if new versions of jest fix this issue

Comment: This was a great suggestion, but it did not resolve the issue for me.  But what it did do was remove one big possibility, which lead me to pursue other possible causes (which I eventually found, see my answer above).  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Adjusting watchman limits worked for me. [This watchman documentation](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/install#macos-file-descriptor-limits) indicates this is only relevant for macOS <= 10.6, but solved my problem on 10.13.6.