# Testing with Jest failed with Error: Error watching file for changes: EMFILE

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jestjs

I tried to write a test for a React.js app.
Everything was going fine but after making the directory tracked with Git(made a Git repo with it).
The test fails with the error below

```js
2017-01-15 05:05 node[1278] (FSEvents.framework) FSEventStreamStart: register_with_server: ERROR: f2d_register_rpc() => (null) (-22)
2017-01-15 05:05 node[1278] (FSEvents.framework) FSEventStreamStart: register_with_server: ERROR: f2d_register_rpc() => (null) (-22)
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Error watching file for changes: EMFILE
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange (fs.js:1406:11)
```

I am sure that this is because of `.git` directory because when I remove `.git` directory it is running without the error.
It seems that the exception occurs in watching the files.
My development environment is MacOS 10.12.2 and Node 6.9.4.
How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: I tried to set ulimit to a large number but no effects.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/33656154/893780

Comment: stackoverflow.com/a/33656154/893780 does not work for me.

Comment: I think there should be a definite solution to make it not watching '.git' directory.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues?q=is%3Aissue+emfile+is%3Aclosed :D

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Oh, I am going to answer my question after hours of my struggling.
The best solution is to install the latest version of [Watchman](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/install.html).
The old version of Watchman causes `fsevents` module throws the exception.

After installing `watchman`, optionally you can run `sudo chown -R $(whoami):staff ~/Library/LaunchAgents` to give the permission.

Comment: Hi, we're getting this same problem, but the watchman fix didn't work... mind a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44596052/jest-watch-npm-t-watch-throwing-errors

Comment: It did not fix the problem for me either.

Answer (score 3):

I have ran into the same problem and upgrade `watchman` didn't fix this for me.
Reading the documentation of Jest, you will find there is an option to disable using `watchman`. So I guess `watchman` is not necessary.

What fixed this for me is to upgrade Jest to the lastest version using `npm install --save-dev jest@latest`.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have watchman installed? I recently had a colleague spill water in my laptop, so after migrating projects etc to a new laptop I had a similar issue. I realised after a bit of head-scratching that i just needed to run `brew install watchman`, assuming that you have homebrew of course.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a permission problem, when you install watchman with homebrew is says you should try brew postinstall watchman.
You will notice the permission error when you do this.

`Error: Permission denied - /usr/local/var/run/watchman
sudo chown -R "$USER":admin /usr/local/var/run`

will solve the permission problem then

```
brew postinstall watchman
```

will work

Answer (score 0):

[This section of create-react-app's README](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#npm-test-hangs-on-macos-sierra) describes possible ways to deal with this pesky issue.

I personally had to reinstall watchman - and tests are running again without a hitch .

Comment: I suppose you saw [this](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/836bb39394bef9d83d4dd0cccea08c156dbf298f/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#npm-test-hangs-on-macos-sierra) version of the docs at the time of your answer.
Spent a bit of time figuring out what the correct version is, figured I'd post it here.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues as above and after seeing the comments, i tried to install watchman by running brew install watchman, but it suggested to upgrade to latest version and i did the same. This resolved my issue and i am able to run my tests in jest using npm test now. Thanks guys

Comment: Is this meant as an answer that can stand alone from the previous ones? Or more of just a "thanks" comment (which should be done as a comment, not an answer)

Comment: Please don't add _"thanks"_ as answers. They don't actually provide an answer to the question, and can be perceived as noise by its future visitors. Instead, [upvote answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) you like. This way future visitors of the question will see a higher vote count on that answer, and the answerer will also be rewarded with reputation points. See [Why is voting important](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).