# jest --watch (npm t -- --watch) throwing errors

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jestjs, watchman

> node[1265] (FSEvents.framework) FSEventStreamStart: register_with_server: ERROR: f2d_register_rpc() => (null) (-22)

This happens when running `npm t -- --watch`. On my system node v7.4.0 it works fine. On my fellow coworker (node v7.9) it fails.

This question here asks the exact problem:

[Testing with Jest failed with Error: Error watching file for changes: EMFILE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41657754/testing-with-jest-failed-with-error-error-watching-file-for-changes-emfile)

---

However the fix "install watchman" didn't work.

We did `brew install watchman` then `brew postinstall watchman`

Then when trying to run `npm t -- --watch` again we get a new error:

> /Users/user/Library/LaunchAgents/com.github.facebook.watchman.plist: Operation not permitted

Anyone else running into a problem with `jest watch`?

The regular `npm t` will work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So we had to install `jest-cli` with `watchman` on his computer...

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how has this resolved the problem?
Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

After installing `watchman`, you can give it a full permission to the launch agents by `sudo chown -R $(whoami):staff ~/Library/LaunchAgents`.
It will resolve the permission issue.